# How to collapse and aggregate rows with character / long string data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates, consolidation

I am working on a large dataset with lots of text data that needs to be consolidated. There are supposedly unique cases / observations, but they do have duplicates. The catch is, that sometimes the duplicates cases provide complimentary and new information. Therefore, I would like to collapse / merge the cases based on criteria.

I have here a very small sample dataset, that illustrates the idea. Please note that in reality the `varText` is often more than 1000 characters long.

`varID` represents the targeted unique observation

`varCat` represents one categorial data, sometimes it contains NA, sometimes it complements an observation (in the actual case, I have about 10 of these)

```r
    varID <- c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'z')
    varText <- c('This is a long text', 'This is also a long text', 
                 'This is short', 'This is another unique long text', 
                 'Blabla1', 'Blabla2', 'Blabla3', 'Blabla4', 'Blabla5', 'Blabla6', 'Blabla7', 
                 'Blabla8', 'This is also a long blabla', 'This case is perfectly fine')
    varCat <- c('CatA', 'CatB', NA, 'CatC', 'CatA', NA, NA, 'CatC', 'CatA', 'CatB', NA, 'CatC', NA, 'CatF')

    df <- data.frame(varID, varText, varCat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Sample df:

```
       varID                          varText varCat
    1      a              This is a long text   CatA
    2      b         This is also a long text   CatB
    3      c                    This is short   <NA>
    4      d This is another unique long text   CatC
    5      e                          Blabla1   CatA
    6      a                          Blabla2   <NA>
    7      b                          Blabla3   <NA>
    8      c                          Blabla4   CatC
    9      d                          Blabla5   CatA
    10     c                          Blabla6   CatB
    11     d                          Blabla7   <NA>
    12     e                          Blabla8   CatC
    13     a       This is also a long blabla   <NA>
    14     z      This case is perfectly fine   CatF
```

First I identify all cases that have duplicates:

```r
df <- df %>% add_count(varID, name = 'dupe_varID')
```

Then I also want to compare the text based on its length:

```r
df$text_length <- stringr::str_length(df$varText)
```

Finally, I create a new dataframe which only has the duplicated cases. And I think I can use `group_by` from `dplyr`. But I don't know how to proceed from here.

```r
# filter all duplicated cases into new df sort ???
df2 <- df %>% filter(dupe_varID > 1) %>% group_by(varID) %>% arrange(desc(text_length), varCat)
```

I would like to have the following result:

- The longest `varText` should be kept
- NA values are replaced with non NAs
- Duplicates are dropped
- If there is a conflict in `varCat` the case with the longest text provides `varCat`

```
 1 a     This is also a long blabla       CatA
 2 b     This is also a long text         CatB
 3 c     This is short                    CatC
 4 d     This is another unique long text CatC
 5 e     Blabla1                          CatA
14 z     This case is perfectly fine      CatF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to group by 'varID', then `fill` the `NA` elements with the adjacent non-NA element and `slice` the row with the `max` number of characters (`nchar`) in 'varText'

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(varID) %>%
   fill(varCat, .direction = 'downup') %>% 
   slice(which.max(nchar(varText)))
# A tibble: 6 x 3
# Groups:   varID [6]
#  varID varText                          varCat
#  <chr> <chr>                            <chr> 
#1 a     This is also a long blabla       CatA  
#2 b     This is also a long text         CatB  
#3 c     This is short                    CatC  
#4 d     This is another unique long text CatC  
#5 e     Blabla1                          CatA  
#6 z     This case is perfectly fine      CatF
```

Comment: Thanks! This is working! I know my question was overly specific (I guess that's where the down votes come from), but I didn't know how to approach the problem.

Btw, should be `.direction = c("down", "up")`